# Add an image to end of video using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to Stack Overflow and JavaScript.
I have a current JavaScript function to get a preview image from a source and present it before playing the video, but what I need help with is to show the same image after the video is done playing.

This is where the code is obtaining the image:

```
function getPreviewImage(){
    if (typeof currVid != 'undefined' && typeof currVid.previewimage != 'undefined' && currVid.previewimage != ''){
            return currVid.previewimage;
    }else{
            return '';
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: And the code that shows that image as preview and plays the video?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to add the image as the last frame of the video.

If you're using html5 video and jquery, I believe there is a video has ended callback:

```
<body>
  ...
  <video>Your video here</video>
  ...
  <script>
    $(function() { // document ready
      $('video').bind('ended', function(){
        // now show image
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: And without jQuery, you can use `element.onended = function () {};` (or with `addEventListener`)

Comment: Sorry. Where exactly would I put that code? (New to javascript)

Comment: You should be able to just put it inside your document ready function.  or have it just before the </body> tag so it runs after the elements have been created.  Non-jquery you'd put it in a window.onload function: window.onload = function () {Javascript code goes here}

Comment: @Oaten... Anyway I can email you the file I so you can take a look at it? To see exactly where to put the code?

Comment: Ah, you must be very new to JS. :) I've updated my code sample above.